# Python, Selenium Webdriver: using xpath to find a "raw" string without a tag in html

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've got a piece of html in which I need to identify if the correct string is present.

Normally I would use either *find_by_xpath*, or *by_id* etc, but that string doesn't have a tag.

The HTML:

*tr class="class_name"*

*td **stringone** /td*

*td **stringtwo** /td*

*td **stringthree** /td*

*/tr*

The string I'm looking for, say, "**stringtwo**", does not have an id, or any other html tags, and therefore I don't know how to find it.

Is there a way to identify the **class_name** in the **tr** tag and then search for a string within it?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: try this... `//tr[@class="class_name"]/td[contains(.,'stringtwo')]`

Comment: *EDIT* sorry, I forgot the closing bracket

Comment: Vivek, is there a "td[DOES_NOT_CONTAIN(.,'string']" as well?

Comment: yes you can do it as `/td[not(contains(.,'string'))]`